# python file open() throws exception for non utf-8 character

Tags: python, file, utf-8

I wrote the simplest python program that exhibits the error I need help with.

```
lines_read = 0
urllist_file = open('../fall11_urls.txt', 'r')

for line in urllist_file:
    lines_read += 1
print('line count:', lines_read)
```

I run this on most files and of course it works as expected but "fall11_urls.txt" is a 14 million line text file that contains URLs, one per line.  Some of these lines contain text with appeaently non utf-8 characters and I get the error quoted below.   I need access every one of these URLs  What is the best way to handle this.  These URLs can be "anything" some are 400 characters of random characters as in "https://bbswigr.fty.com/_Kcsnuk4J71A/RjzGhXZGmfI/AAAARg/xP3FO-Xbt68/s320/Axolo.jpg  Some of these string contain characters such as 0x96  I need my python program to be robust against whatever might be in the file.  (If it matters this runs on Ubuntu 16.04)

Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./count_lines.py", line 2, in <module>
    for line in urllist_file:
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/cvml3/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 5529: invalid start byte
```

One more bit of information iconv finds the same problem with the same file.  See below

```
$ iconv ../fall11_urls.txt >> /dev/null
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 1042953625
```

My current work around is UGLY.  I use iconv to find the problem then I hand edit the file in vi, then process it. and keep doing this until it is clean  but I have MILLIONS of lines in many files to process. And the URLs do mostly work after I hand correct them so these are not noise or "flipped bits".

Comment: Read as binary and then decode it to your required format

Comment: IMO the sanest way is to use `errors='surrogateescape'`. There aren't any *good* ways.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question to let you all know what worked.  Yes opening in binary worked I tried it but then I don't have a "text" file.   I read up on encoding and found the following works because every binary character value is valid.  It is the Safest thing to do.

```
urllist_file = open('../fall11_urls.txt', 'r',   encoding="latin-1")
```

It seems that anyone opening text files they get from other people and have no way to control or know in advance what is inside might be advised to use "latin-1" because there are no invalid byte values in Latin-1.

Thanks.  The suggestion to open in binary got me to investigate what other parameters open() accepts.  I'm new to Python and was astounded to find that strings are just a list of bytes.  (That is what 20+ years of working in C will condition you to expect.)

Comment: You may enjoy reading [this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Answer (score -1):

Did you try crook method? This should work. 
urllist_file = open('../fall11_urls.txt', 'rb') then convert to whatever format you want